# Windows 11 MS Paint not staring with a Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll error

Tags: windows-11, dll, regsvr32

When I try and start MS Paint in Windows 11 I get the follow error.

```
Faulting application name: mspaint.exe, version: 11.2302.19.0, time stamp: 0x64639ec7
Faulting module name: ucrtbase.dll, version: 10.0.22621.608, time stamp: 0xf5fc15a3
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x000000000007f61e
Faulting process ID: 0x0x8808
Faulting application start time: 0x0x1D9BC4BA229C1FF
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Paint_11.2302.19.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\PaintApp\mspaint.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
Report ID: 90b5045f-e19f-443b-b51a-cb1071344570
Faulting package full name: Microsoft.Paint_11.2302.19.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Faulting package-relative application ID: App
```

And

```
Fault bucket 1176766957305647260, type 5
Event Name: MoBEX
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0
Problem signature:
P1: Microsoft.Paint_11.2302.19.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
P2: praid:App
P3: 11.2302.19.0
P4: 64639ec7
P5: ucrtbase.dll
P6: 10.0.22621.608
P7: f5fc15a3
P8: 000000000007f61e
P9: c0000409
P10: 0000000000000007
Attached files:
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER.25683e62-0d33-421c-8dfb-3e5712406e9e.tmp.mdmp
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER.4e2388c6-a692-4c47-ae41-9066849661eb.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER.0279b30c-995a-4e11-9996-404a56f5686a.tmp.csv
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER.f095d88b-5b77-4925-bee8-a0cc5c59f975.tmp.txt
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER.408f73ee-3377-4e5e-81e7-078306a9d6eb.tmp.xml
These files may be available here:
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_Microsoft.Paint__745374c5bbdaaca14d4291cabf3037ab7a40f6ea_83183516_30be4c46-3b88-4fd3-a54e-5876b509eb52
Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 13a0ad8b-c8e2-40ac-b92a-f1a8565bbf52
Report Status: 268435456
Hashed bucket: fb8caa6ac50f766fe054b750199ed09c
Cab Guid: 0
```

I have tried various combinations of  sfc /scannow  , DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth and I have even done a windows reinstall preserving existing apps, files etc.
I tried a regsvr32 ucrtbase.dll
and got a

```
"The module "ucrtbase.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DLLRegisterServer was not found. Make sure that 'ucrtbase" is a valid dll or ocx file and then try againI
```

I have also reinstalled paint a few times.

M/B is a gigabyte M/B and drivers are latest gigabyte drivers (Though that could be problematic in its own right)

Any ideas what is going wrong and how to fix it ?

Thanks in Advance

Rob
(Question also posted on Microsoft support site)

Comment: ucrtbase.dll is not a COM DLL so trying to register it is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

> tried various combinations of sfc /scannow , DISM.exe /Online
> /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
>
> I have even done a windows reinstall preserving existing apps,

Repair Install keeping everything keeps the user profile - **important.**

So now, either the operating system is more seriously damaged than Repair can fix and / or the Windows User Profile is damaged (not easily fixed).

The fastest and easiest solution now is to back everything up and reinstall Windows.  Install Apps and recover data.

Comment: Before you reinstall Windows, check if it's a user profile issue: create a new user, and try paint. Also, rather than go to all the trouble of reinstalling Windows just for paint, if that's the *only* issue, I'd suggest installing an alternative, e.g., free, more powerful, Paint.net, https://paint.net/, or Krita, https://krita.org/en/, or any of the dozens of alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the profile.  I will give that a try !